# System.InvalidCastException: 'Specified cast is not valid.' error

Tags: vb.net

I want to put some thing in web page text area from a textbox with HTML code

```
<input class="input-block-level" type="text" name="notification_address" id="notification_address" autocomplete="true" spellcheck="false" placeholder="Email Address" value="">
```

I get error "cast is not valid"

Code I have tried:

```
Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_DoWork(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.DoWork
     Me.WebBrowser1.Navigate("website")
     WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("notification_address").SetAttribute("value", TextBox1.Text)
End Sub
```

Error occurs only when i execute code in background worker if i do this on button click code runs smoothly.

Comment: That's wrong on a number of levels. Firstly, as it specifically states in the documentation, you should NEVER refer to a control in the `DoWork` event handler. That handler is executed on a secondary thread and you can only safely access controls on the UI thread. Secondly, you can't call `Navigate` and expect the document to be loaded immediately. You have to handle the `DocumentCompleted` event and access the document there. Plenty of examples about of doing that.

Comment: Accessing the WebBrowser.Document property from a worker thread is troublesome.  It has *some* support for it, COM automatically marshals the call to the UI thread.  But not every DOM object has the plumbing available to make that work.  Which is why you get the ICE.  There is nothing there that actually requires you to use a worker thread.  WebBrowser is already heavily multi-threaded by itself, the Navigate() call takes very little time.  You must however call the GetElementById() in the DocumentCompleted event handler, it takes time to load the DOM.